# How can I get Chinese first letter(Pinyin) by using Go language?

Tags: go

I got a question here.I need to get the pinyin of a Chinese word using golang.For example:

---

What I want to get from Chinese "世界" is letter "S" except "世".

---

Can go language do this automatically?

Comment: You can get the first Unicode code point out various ways. `func firstRune(str string) rune { for _, r := range str { return r }; return 0 }` or `func firstRune(str string) { if len(str) > 0 { return []rune(str)[0] } else { return 0 } }`, or probably better ones using `unicode` or some other standard package.

Comment: `[]rune(str)[0]` is an unnecessary copy.

Comment: I know. :) Your answer's better. Would have edited it to 'You can convert the entire string to runes for other manipulations with `runes := []rune(str)`.' but my 5 min ran out.

Comment: THis is what I want .https://github.com/axgle/pinyin

Answer (score 4):

Using the utf8 package you can do something like:

```
func firstLetter(s string) string {
    _, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s)
    return s[:size]
}
```

or

```
func firstLetter(s string) string {
    for _, l := range s {
        return string(l)
    }
    return ""
}
```

You can't do `s[0]` since that would return the first byte of the multi-byte rune.

Comment: Sorry,maybe I didn't explain what I want correctly.Your answer is like getting first letter of a string. But it's not what I want.I edit the question again.

Answer (score 1):

Use [github.com/mozillazg/go-pinyin](https://github.com/mozillazg/go-pinyin)

```
package main                                                               

import (
        "fmt"                                                                        
        "github.com/mozillazg/go-pinyin"                                        
)                                                                               

var a = pinyin.NewArgs()                                                        

func FirstLetterOfPinYin(r rune) string {                                       
        result := pinyin.Pinyin(string(r), a)                                   
        return string(result[0][0][0])                                          
}

func main() {
        fmt.Println(FirstLetterOfPinYin('世'))
        fmt.Println(FirstLetterOfPinYin('界'))
}
```

If you have string of Chinese characters, you can [range the string](https://siongui.github.io/2016/02/03/go-iterate-over-utf8-non-ascii-string/) to get rune of the chars.